# How to not call parent constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

When an instance of an inherited class is created, it runs its parent constructor, too. 
How can I make my child so it doesn't call my parent constructor?

```
 class parent {

    int a;

    parent() {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}

class child extends parent {

    child() {
        System.out.println("child");
    }

}

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        child a = new child();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's impossible. Look into inheritance.

Comment: So I must make sure that the parent's constructor doesn't do anything that I don't want my childs to do?

Comment: It's like giving birth to your kid, such that you are not your kid's parent. Which is impossible.

Comment: Maybe inheritance isn't appropriate here.

Comment: I was mainly curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is not possible. If you're in a scenario where you think this is necessary, something is wrong with your design.

That being said, you can get away with something similar by adding another constructor to your parent class and explicitly calling it:

```
class Parent {

    int a;

    Parent() {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }

    Parent(boolean unused){
       //do nothing
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    Child() {
        super(false);
        System.out.println("child");
    }

}

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Child a = new Child();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the base class constructor private, if you do not need to make multiple instances of the base class.